# calculate mobile device linear movement (Android)

Tags: android, accelerometer

Is there any method of calculating linear distance using accelerometer and gyroscope sensor data as double integral on acceleration seems to give lot of drift.

Note : Image processing techniques using the camera / GPS seem to be a heavy duty on battery.

Comment: Many people have tried to measure the linear displacement using accelerometer and gyro sensors. To the best of my knowledge, unfortunately, it is practically impossible to achieve it solely employing the sensors.

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish to calculate linear distance, you should not read from raw Accelerometer data. In API 9. android introduced [Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION), which is nothing but the gravity component deducted from raw accelerometer values.

The drift can build up much quickly if there is even a single degree error in your own calculations for finding linear component in raw data. Check out an experiences from Google: [SensorFusion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k).

The question is very similar to [Calculating distance using Linear acceleration android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926459/calculating-distance-using-linear-acceleration-android?rq=1)

Comment: Your Sensor Fusion link has nothing to do with linear movement. It's only orientation.